# RegExp only - check if text contains specified character within provided range of occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, full-text-search, find-occurrences

I would like to check if f.e letter "a" occurs between 3 and 5 times (inclusive), in total, within provided text input.

**Given:**

1. `zayaaxaawv` <- 5 of "a", passed
2. `zayaxawva` <- 4 of "a", passed
3. `zaaay` <- 3 of "a", passed
4. `zayax` <- 2 of "a", failed
5. `zayaaxaaaw` <- 6 of "a", failed

Examples 1-3 passed and 4-5 failed.

I know it can be done in JavaScript without using `RegExp`, f.e:

```
const txt = `zayaxawva`;
const charCountByFilter = [...txt].filter(letter => letter === 'a').length;
const charCountByMatch = txt.match(/a/g).length;

console.log('isInRange by filter', isInRange(charCountByFilter));
console.log('isInRange by match', isInRange(charCountByMatch));

function isInRange(value) {
    return value >= 3 && value <= 5;
}
```

However, is it possible to do it entirely by RegExp? I thought of something similar to`/a{3,5}/.test(txt)`, but it only counts subsequent "a" chars, not all of them.

Comment: Yes, it is easy, `^(?:[^a]*a){3,5}[^a]*$`

Comment: Ok, it seems to work. Could you please describe this RegExp with details? It doesn't look easy to me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:[^a]*a){3,5}[^a]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uskDZ2/1). Details:

- `^` - start of a string anchor
- `(?:[^a]*a){3,5}` - a non-capturing group matching three, four or five occurrences of

  - `[^a]*` - zero or more chars other than `a`
  - `a` - an `a` char
- `[^a]*` - zero or more chars other than `a`
- `$` - end of the string anchor.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ['zayaaxaawv','zayaxawva','zaaay','zayax','zayaaxaaaw'];
const l = 'a', min = 3, max = 5;
const rx = new RegExp(`^(?:[^${l}]*${l}){${min},${max}}[^${l}]*$`);
strings.forEach(x => console.log(x, '=>', rx.test(x)));
```